# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when connecting to my RaspberryPi via External IP

Tags: networking, google-chrome, raspberry-pi

I am trying to set up a web server on my raspberry pi. I can connect to it inside my current network by using my raspberry pi's ip address, but when using the port forward (my routers ip adress:port), I get:

This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

The connection to (my routers ip address) was interrupted.

Extra info that may help:
I have tried with HTTP and HTTPS and no difference.

Client devices are allowed to access the configuration page.

I also tried from a different network and I'm still getting the same error.

i have a Linksys E3200

Comment: what other information should i include?

Comment: Are you trying to using a secure http connection when you get this error?  Is your router configured to allow wireless clients access the configuration page?

Comment: I have tried with HTTP and HTTPS and no difference. Client devices are allowed to access the configuration page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've often had this problem myself, and not with just my raspberry pi.

Your router is blocking the connection, regardless of what ports you have setup. Assuming you've already attempted to port forward (not port triggering, there is a difference), try putting your raspberry pi in a DMZ instead. This allows all incoming traffic to be forwarded to your pi, regardless of the source. It's not the most secure thing in the world, but it would get you by for now.

My solution to the problem, was to factory reset my router. I've had routers running both stock and ddwrt firmware do this and I'm not quite sure what the cause of it is. If DMZ or factory reset doesn't work, try implementing a new router (borrow a friends) and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The model router you have is the same one I had problems with myself (go figure). The DMZ Setting would be under NAT/QOS, or essentially the same place that you saw those port forwarding options. As for factory resetting your router, you can either press and hold the physical reset button for 30 seconds on your router, or you can go under the administration page and there should be an option to restore to factory defaults.

Comment: DMZ fixed it! yeeeeeeeeey!

Answer (score 1):

Without more information on the service/application you are trying to reach, it may be worth confirming that the requests are indeed rejected by the router and not by the Pi itself.
To do this you can run `sudo tcpdump -i eth0 port [port] and '(tcp-syn|tcp-ack)!=0'` on your Pi to log the network traffic.
Check you do see packets logged when you connect from within the LAN (if not: try to replace eth0 by the other network interfaces available).
Once this works, try to access the service through your public IP and check if something gets logged: if there's something, then your Pi does receive the request but does not respond to it. If you get nothing, the connection is dropped somewhere else on the network.
You can perform that test from both a machine inside the LAN and an external network (phone, friend): if it works from an external client but not from within your own LAN, it's most likely some limitation of your router not allowing loopback connection.

In case this you need more help, please include more detailed information such as:
 - The service you're trying to setup
 - The brand ad model of your router (with the version of the firmware in case you installed some custom one like DD-WRT or Tomato)
 - The details of what you have set in your router configuration

Comment: the log is printing much faster than I can read it. After a minute or so, I canceled the process. Here is what I received: 77104 packets captured
77105 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

Comment: So at least something can access that port apparently. ;-)
As written above, it will be difficult to help further without more details regarding what you are trying to achieve.